# How to Decode base 64 data

Tags: java, xml, jpeg, base64

I have an XML doucment in which there is an tag for image like this

if there is an image then the tag would be as follows

```
<thumbnail>
<type>IMAGE JPG</type>
<data> base64 data </data>
</thumbnail>
```

And if there is no image then

```
<thumbnail/>
```

I want to get the base64 encoded image using DOM parser
and how to handle tags which don't have any image like `<thumbnail/>`

In the XML document there will be any number of  tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [COS](http://www.servlets.com/cos/) package has a [Base64Decoder](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/Base64Decoder.html). [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) offers an [alternative](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). Also one may use `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`, but that makes one's code Sun JDK-specific.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to DOM coding, you could do it declaratively in an XSLT stylesheet.

XSLT does not have any built-in features to base64 decode, but you can use the Saxon extension function **xs:base64Binary-to-octet** to stream it out to a file using the Java FileOutputStream in an XSLT stylesheet:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:fos="java.io.FileOutputStream">

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <!--Your example did not reveal the document structure.
     Assuming thumbnail elements are children of the document element-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/thumbnail" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!--For thumbnail elements that contain data, decode the BASE64 encoded content and write to file -->
    <xsl:template match="thumbnail[data]">
       <xsl:variable name="img" select="concat('c:\test\', position(), '.jpg')"/>
       <xsl:variable name="fos" select="fos:new(string($img))"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="fos:write($fos,saxon:base64Binary-to-octets(xs:base64Binary(data/text())))"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="fos:close($fos)"/>
    </xsl:template>

 <!--Do nothing with empty thumbnail elements-->
 <xsl:template match="thumbnail" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```